# Can I display the image from the QR code containing the URL of the image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, qr-code

Do I encode  the QR code so that the images will be displayed in the MVC  C# application?

Comment: Yes, No or Maybe. Perhaps a better suggestion would be possible after some more details.

Comment: i'm  using ZXing library to scan the QR code. I want the image from the QR code to be displayed on the website.

Comment: Scanners don't see a barcode as an image, but only see text encoded within. If you want to display that barcode you have to recreate it as an image and display it on the site.

Comment: I can recommend the [QRCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder) to create QR-Images

Comment: Recreate it as an image? I've already saved the image into the server by using the server url to generate the QR code. Now,  I'm trying to get the image to be displayed into the website once the QR code is captured.